# Change each bar color according to the value in wpf toolkit barchart

Tags: wpf, bar-chart, wpftoolkit

Below is the chart in which I am trying to style each bar but the color for whole series is changing. Please help.

```
<chartingToolkit:Chart Name="ChartFinger1" Title="1st Finger" Margin="10" Width="450" >
    <chartingToolkit:ColumnSeries ItemsSource="{Binding ChartDataFinger1}" 
      IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Key}" DependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Value}">
        <chartingToolkit:ColumnSeries.DataPointStyle>
            <Style TargetType="chartingToolkit:ColumnDataPoint">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
            </Style>
        </chartingToolkit:ColumnSeries.DataPointStyle>
    </chartingToolkit:ColumnSeries>
</chartingToolkit:Chart>
```

Comment: Have you tried adding a couple of triggers to your Style? The way it is now it's not surprising all of them change color.

Comment: You mean something like [THIS](https://i.imgur.com/HLDaefF.png) ?